# springwebflow transition to error page

Tags: html, spring, spring-webflow

I have my spring webflow like this:

```
<var name="moneyTransfer" class="com.wu.pos.domain.impl.MoneyTransferImpl" />
<view-state id="releaseMTCN" view="additionalservices/releaseMT/releaseMTCN" model="moneyTransfer">

</view-state>

<end-state id="success" />
<end-state id="error" />
<end-state id="terminate" />

<global-transitions>
    <transition on="back" to="breadcrumbListener.back(context)" />
    <transition on="releaseMTCN" to="error" />
    <transition on="cancel" to="terminate" bind="false" validate="false" />
    <transition on="terminate" to="terminate" bind="false" />
</global-transitions>
```

I have an html button. When I click on that html button it should display a pop up and should stay on the same page, but it is displaying a popup and within millisecs it is going to next page.

When checking in console I have the following error:

> org.springframework.webflow.engine.NoMatchingTransitionException: No transition found on occurence of event 'next' in state 'releaseMTCN' of flow 'additionalservices-releaseMTCN' -- valid transitional criteria are array[[empty]] -- likely programmer error, check the set of TransitionCriteria for this state

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is pretty clear. You're missing a transition tag for 'next'.

When some one clicks on the next button (inside the view-state 'releaseMTCN') a 'next' event is fired... meaning in order to handle this 'next' event you need to define a transition tag where the on attribute value is equal to "next" either inside the 'releaseMTCN' view-state or inside your global transitions

like so:

```
<transition on="next" to="breadcrumbListener.next(context)" />
```